# How to avoid repetitive code intensive if statements in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am currently working on a text based RPG and am still learning java and programming in general. My question is this, I have come to a point in my program where the user will select their units and I dont know how to accomplish this without large if statements that are very restrictive in terms of expanding or altering the game play. How could I write something that could condense my if statements and have a more modular approve overall?

Here is what the user first see:

Welcome to RPG Game!

Please select 3 units!

Enter 1 to add a Ranger 100 4 10

Enter 2 to add a Heavy 100 4 15

enter 3 to add a Medic 100 4 10

To respond to this I have codded the following

```
if (resp == 1){
      if (rangerCount == 0){
      ArrayList<Item> rangerInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Ranger rangerObj0 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInv0);

      rangerObj0.pickUp(mh1000);
      rangerObj0.pickUp(s1000);
      rangerObj0.pickUp(t1000);

      rangerObj0.equip(mh1000);
      rangerObj0.equip(s1000);
      rangerObj0.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(rangerObj0);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      rangerCount++;
      }
      else if (rangerCount == 1){
      ArrayList<Item> rangerInv1 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Ranger rangerObj1 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInv1);

      rangerObj1.pickUp(mh1000);
      rangerObj1.pickUp(s1000);
      rangerObj1.pickUp(t1000);

      rangerObj1.equip(mh1000);
      rangerObj1.equip(s1000);
      rangerObj1.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(rangerObj1);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      rangerCount++;
      }
      else if (rangerCount == 2){
      ArrayList<Item> rangerInv2 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Ranger rangerObj2 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInv2);

      rangerObj2.pickUp(mh1000);
      rangerObj2.pickUp(s1000);
      rangerObj2.pickUp(t1000);

      rangerObj2.equip(mh1000);
      rangerObj2.equip(s1000);
      rangerObj2.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(rangerObj2);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      rangerCount++;
      }
    } 
    else if (resp == 2) {
      if (heavyCount == 0) {
      ArrayList<Item> heavyInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Heavy heavyObj0 = new Heavy("Heavy", 100, 4, 15, heavyInv0);

      heavyObj0.pickUp(mh4000);
      heavyObj0.pickUp(s1000);
      heavyObj0.pickUp(t1000);

      heavyObj0.equip(mh4000);
      heavyObj0.equip(s1000);
      heavyObj0.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(heavyObj0);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      heavyCount++;
      }
      else if (heavyCount == 1){
      ArrayList<Item> heavyInv1 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Heavy heavyObj1 = new Heavy("Heavy", 100, 4, 15, heavyInv1);

      heavyObj1.pickUp(mh4000);
      heavyObj1.pickUp(s1000);
      heavyObj1.pickUp(t1000);

      heavyObj1.equip(mh4000);
      heavyObj1.equip(s1000);
      heavyObj1.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(heavyObj1);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      heavyCount++;
      }
      else if (heavyCount == 2){
      ArrayList<Item> heavyInv2 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Heavy heavyObj2 = new Heavy("Heavy", 100, 4, 15, heavyInv2);

      heavyObj2.pickUp(mh4000);
      heavyObj2.pickUp(s1000);
      heavyObj2.pickUp(t1000);

      heavyObj2.equip(mh4000);
      heavyObj2.equip(s1000);
      heavyObj2.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(heavyObj2);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      heavyCount++;
      }
    } 
    else if (resp == 3) {
      if (medicCount == 0) {
      ArrayList<Item> medicInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Medic medicObj0 = new Medic("Medic", 100, 4, 10, medicInv0);

      medicObj0.pickUp(mh3000);
      medicObj0.pickUp(s1000);
      medicObj0.pickUp(t1000);

      medicObj0.equip(mh3000);
      medicObj0.equip(s1000);
      medicObj0.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(medicObj0);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      medicCount++;
      }
      else if (medicCount == 1) {
      ArrayList<Item> medicInv1 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Medic medicObj1 = new Medic("Medic", 100, 4, 10, medicInv1);

      medicObj1.pickUp(mh3000);
      medicObj1.pickUp(s1000);
      medicObj1.pickUp(t1000);

      medicObj1.equip(mh3000);
      medicObj1.equip(s1000);
      medicObj1.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(medicObj1);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      medicCount++;
      }
      else if (medicCount == 2) {
      ArrayList<Item> medicInv2 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Medic medicObj2 = new Medic("Medic", 100, 4, 10, medicInv2);

      medicObj2.pickUp(mh3000);
      medicObj2.pickUp(s1000);
      medicObj2.pickUp(t1000);

      medicObj2.equip(mh3000);
      medicObj2.equip(s1000);
      medicObj2.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(medicObj2);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      medicCount++;
      }
    } 
    else {
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid responce!");
    }
```

The objects you see referenced in the multiple instances of pickUp() and equip() look like this for reference:

```
static Item mh1000 = new Item ("AR1", "Damage", 2, null, 0, null, 0, false, false);
```

to me this all seems very cumbersome. What if I want to make it a game with 5 units or 10 units, do I really have to add 2 to 7 lines of code per entry to accomplish this? it seems like there should be a much easier way to do this. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, this is extremely cumbersome.  To streamline this you will need to learn about data structures, and modifying your code to do that is far beyond the scope and purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: Also note that your code contains some serious variable-scope errors. For example `ArrayList<Item> rangerInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();` -- the `rangerInv0` object ceases to exist as soon as control leaves the enclosing block.  I believe you have a significant amount to learn about Java, and programming in general, before you are ready to tackle an RPG like this.  Unfortunately, hand-holding at this level is not on-topic here.

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: One last comment: It is very encouraging that you wrote this code and intuited that there is a better way.  This indicates to me that, once you learn the basics, you will probably be very successful.  That "can I do this better" attitude is a hallmark of all good software engineers.

Comment: You can move the `pickup` and `equip` calls to the respective constructors. That would be a good start to cleaning this up. The `rangerCount` logic is confusing me a little, however. Whatever it is trying to do, it can likely be make a bit more generic and elegant as well.

Comment: I agree with you that based on your response this would be to large a topic to cover here however, is there a specific topic in data structures I could look into related to this? Also, is there a specific term or phrase for what I am trying to do here?

Comment: @DarthBusiness Start from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTB0EiLXUC8

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you recognize that your code is becoming harder to maintain as the code is becoming longer is a good sign, and is a good indication that it's time to refactor. The basic building blocks for structuring code in Java are Classes and Methods.

A Class should represent a type of entity in your system and contain behavior (methods) and state (attributes) related to that type.

A good start would be to extract the repeating sections of code into methods, and then call them when needed. If you find you are duplicating sections of common code, this is another good indication that you need to refactor.

There are no hard and fast rules about 'how large is too large' or 'how small is too small', but you'll learn a general gut feel. If a method is too large that's it's difficult to read/understand/change, then your gut feel is probably right, split it up into smaller, easier to manage methods. Similarly for Classes. If you have too many methods in a Class to the point also where it's too hard to maintain, time to split into different Classes.